# How to store a CSV file as an array of floats in C

Tags: arrays, csv, matrix

I'm new to programming. One of the tasks I've been set involves reading a CSV file (with 2 columns of 12 numbers) into a 2D array. How would I go about doing this in C code? Would something like this work?

```
for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
        fscanf(liftcoeff,"%f,%f",&array1,&array2);
        array[i][j] = array1,array2;
    }
}
```

or like this?

```
for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
        fscanf(liftcoeff,"%f,%f",array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Is your code compiling? What happens when you run it?

Comment: What is meant by `array[i][j] = array1,array2;`? I'm not sure that comma means what you think it means.

Comment: Before, it was compiling, but would print 2 columns of 24 (of which only 12 of the first column would print correct values). I thought the `array[i][j] = array1,array2;` meant store floats array1 and array2 in the the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your looping logic.  Your outer for loop is responsible for looping through the 12 lines of your file. The inner for loop is responsible for hitting both columns, but your fscanf call is looking for 2 floats separated by a comma.  Essentially you are attempting to read twice as much data as exists.

**Edit:**
Unfortunately not at a machine with a C compiler at the moment, but the following should be close enough.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    fscanf(liftcoeff, "%f,%f", &array[i][0], &array[i][1]);
}
```

Then you can verify you've read the data correctly by printing it to screen.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    printf("%f,%f", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
}
```

And don't forget to close your file when you're done `fclose(lifecoeff);`

**Edit 2:**
As suggested in comments, some very rudimentary error checking:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    int count = fscanf(liftcoeff, "%f,%f", &array[i][0], &array[i][1]);

    // Handle early end of file, as in there were fewer than 12 lines.
    if (count == EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unexpected end of file.\n");
        break;
    }
    // Handle line of CSV not matching two floats separated by comma. 
    else if(count != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fscanf matching error line %d\n", i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Maybe you could mention using the return value of fscanf for error checking? You could end up with some really funky values in those arrays if your input is incomplete.